# Including hash in rspec facts

Tags: rspec, puppet

For a Puppet RSpec test, I would like to define a fact as

```
let (:facts) {{
  :os => { 'name' => 'CentOS' }
}}
```

However, RSpec does not seem to recognize os as hash when running Puppet 3.7.4.  The `validate_hash($::os)` function of stdlib does not return an error and a test of the variable within the manifest of

```
if $::os == undef {
   fail("Fact os is undefined")
}
```

suggests that os is indeed defined.

Would you please provide guidance on how to set a hash value for a fact to be used in a Puppet RSpect test?  Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Why do you think it is not a hash? What is not working?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: In the real world, does `puppet apply -e 'notice $::os["name"]'` work for you?

Answer (score 1):

`{ 'name', 'CentOS' }` is not a valid hash. Did you mean `:os => { 'name' => 'CentOS' }`?

Comment: You are right.  I had mistakenly used a , rather than a =>.

Comment: I realize that my explanation may be confusing.  In my description of the problem, I had mistakenly used a , rather than a =>.  If you have a suggestion on how to set a hash value for a fact, I would be most appreciative.